# JavaScript метод sort() и Math.random()

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Изучаю JavaScript, метод **sort()**
Все в общем-то понятно было, но далее я встретил пример из учебника с методом `Math.random()` :

Задание:

> Используйте функцию sort для того, чтобы «перетрясти» элементы массива в случайном порядке.

Решение(дано в учебнике, но без объяснений):

> Функция сортировки должна возвращать случайный результат сравнения. Используйте для этого Math.random.
>
> Обычно Math.random() возвращает результат от 0 до 1. Вычтем 0.5, чтобы область значений стала [-0.5 ... 0.5).
>
> ```js
> var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
>
> function compareRandom(a, b) {
>   return Math.random() - 0.5;
> }
>
> arr.sort(compareRandom);
>
> alert( arr ); // элементы в случайном порядке, например [3,5,1,2,4]
> ```

Долго думал. Я так понимаю действие данной `return Math.random() - 0.5;` строчки:
"универсальный алгоритм сортировки" берет два числа(a и b), далее запускается `return Math.random() - 0.5;` если число *меньше ноля*, первым в записи идет **a**(сортировка поставит a по меньшему индексу), если *больше ноля*, первым идет в записи **b**( сортировка поставит b по меньшему индексу). Чтобы было нагляднее, я нарисовал схему(на примере(2, 4)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**1).** Мой первый вопрос, правильно ли я понимаю работу данной функции. Также хочется узнать доступным языком принцип действия "универсальный алгоритм сортировки".

// ######

На данном этапе изучения JavaScript я понял, что в функции, в скобках передаются значения, и конечно они используются в самой функции, вот пример:

```js
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

var arr = [ 1, 2, 15 ];

arr.sort(compareNumeric);

alert(arr);  // 1, 2, 15
```

Но в первом примере, в функции, *a* и *b* не используются, а сразу идет `return`, поэтому я попробовал совсем их убрать и записал так:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function compareRandom() {
  return Math.random() - 0.5;
}

arr.sort(compareRandom);

alert( arr );
```

Удивительно, но все работает и так.

**2).** Мой второй вопрос, в данном случае можно в скобках совсем не указывать *a* и *b*? Почему тогда в учебнике запись *(a,b)*

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в JS можно всегда не указывать параметры функции и брать из аргументов их. Но это неудобно,  поэтому и пишут параметры в явном виде чтобы подчеркнуть сколько их будет (по сути это вопрос стиля кода, не более). Принцип вы понимаете правильно, но будьте аккуратный с такими сортировками, в ряде языков получите совсем не то, что вы ожидание, т.к. оператор сравнения должен быть антисимметричным, транзитивным и антирефлексивным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"но все работает и так" - где ж работает? Массив ведь не отсортирован. Такая `compare` функция возвращает случайный результат, в массиве после "сортировки" элементы будут идти в произвольном порядке.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var count = 0;
function compareRandom() {
  count++;
  return Math.random() - 0.5;
}

arr.sort(compareRandom);

console.log(count);
console.log( arr );
```

Обратите внимание на меняющееся значение `count`. Теоретически, такая "сортировка" может никогда не закончиться, так как два сравнения одной и той же пары чисел могут дать противоположные результаты.

А, по пунктам:

1. Да, понимаете правильно.
2. Да, можно не указывать.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var count = 0;
function compareNumeric(a, b) {
  count++;
  return a - b;
}

arr.sort(compareNumeric);

console.log(count);
console.log( arr );
```

Во время нормальной (с `compareNumeric`) сортировки массива необходимо выполнить определенное количество сравнений пар элементов. В зависимости от начального расположения элементов в массиве, некоторые пары будут сравниваться несколько раз. Логика сортировки базируется на том, что повторные сравнения чисел 2 и 3 возвращают результат, показывающий, что три больше двух. Если у этих повторных сравнений результат - случайный, то как в конце концов дожны располагаться числа 2 и 3 в окончательном отсортированном массиве?

Comment: Да, в учебнике, в задании, как раз и была задача, чтобы элементы массива после сортировки шли в случайном порядке(про это, я добавил в свой вопрос). Про `count` я не очень понял; то что там счетчик меняется, это мне понятно, но чтобы понять почему он меняется видимо и нужно изучить "универсальный алгоритм сортировки", реализованный внутри самого интерпретатора JavaScript, верно? и видимо это отдельная тема.

Comment: `два сравнения одной и той же пары чисел могут дать противоположные результаты` - никто не сравнивает одни и те же числа повторно(кроме bogosort), незачем перепроверять алгоритм сравнения. Число сравнений меняется, потому что по сути это разные входы, числам соответствуют разные веса. Перемешайте массив перед сортировкой и проинспектируйте число сравнений во втором сниппете.