# Рандомные числа от 1 до 5 без повторения 2 раза подряд

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая выводит рандомные числа от 1 до 4. Как сделать так, чтобы предыдущее число не выводилось опять. То есть не может к примеру выпасть 1, а потом опять 1, а должна быть другая цифра:

```
let getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
    let number = Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
    return number;
};

getRandomNumber(1, 5);
```

Comment: Сохранять число в переменную и сравнивать следующее с предыдущим.

Comment: А через одно числа могут повторяться?

Comment: Да,главное чтобы подряд не повторялись.К примеру должно быть так 3 4 3 2 3 4 1 2 4 3.

Comment: @JamesHetfield Усильте это в вопросе. Судя по ответам, Вас не поняли.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const numbers = []
const getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
  const number = Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min))
  if (numbers.includes(number)) return getRandomNumber(min, max)
  else {
    numbers.push(number)
    return number
  }
}
console.log(getRandomNumber(1, 5))
console.log(getRandomNumber(1, 5))
console.log(getRandomNumber(1, 5))
console.log(getRandomNumber(1, 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

Практически то же, что у @Igor, но через генератор:

```js
function * getRandomInt(from, to) {
  if (to - from < 2) throw 'Incorrect interval';
  let prev, cur;
  while (true) {
    while (prev == cur) {
      cur = Math.floor(from + Math.random() * (to - from));
    }
    yield cur;
    prev = cur;
  }
}

let rnd = getRandomInt(1, 5);
let numbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  numbers.push(rnd.next().value);
}
console.log(numbers + '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант такой - создавать массив с числами из заданного промежутка, перемешать его и выдавать по одному числу.

```js
const getNotRepeatRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
  const shuffle = (arr) => {
   let j, temp;
   for(var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
    j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i + 1));
    temp = arr[j];
    arr[j] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
   }
   return arr;
  }
  let array = [];
  for (let index = min; index <= max; index++) {
    array.push(index);
  }
  array = shuffle(array);
  return () => array.shift();
};

const getRandomNumber = getNotRepeatRandomNumber(1, 4);
console.log(getRandomNumber());
console.log(getRandomNumber());
console.log(getRandomNumber());
console.log(getRandomNumber());
```

Если же вам нужно чтобы не повторялись только 2 соседних числа, то возможно вам подойдет такой вариант

```js
let getNotRepeatRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
  let lastNumber;
  const getRandomNumber = () => Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
  const result = () => {
    const number = getRandomNumber();
    if (number === lastNumber) {
      return result();
    } 
    lastNumber = number;
    return number;
  };
  return result;
};

const getRandomNumber = getNotRepeatRandomNumber(1, 4);
console.log(getRandomNumber());
console.log(getRandomNumber());
console.log(getRandomNumber());
console.log(getRandomNumber());
```

Comment: `array.sort((a, b) => Math.random() < 0.5 ? a - b : b - a);` - это зло. Здесь будет двойная алгоритмическся сложность.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629760/javascript-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-sort-%D0%B8-math-random

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко спасибо, поменял на менее затратный алгоритм

Answer (score 1):

```js
let getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
  let last = getRandomNumber.last;
  let result = last;
  while (result == last) {
    result = Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
  }
  getRandomNumber.last = result;
  return result;
};

var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  a.push(getRandomNumber(1, 5));
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```